# OSX GL_TIMESTAMP vs GL_TIME_ELAPSED

Tags: macos, opengl, timestamp

I have some code on OSX that measures GPU time. However, when I call `glGetQueryObjectui64v` with `GL_TIMESTAMP`, it always returns 0. I am calling `glGetQueryObjectiv` with `GL_QUERY_RESULT_AVAILABLE` before to make sure it's ready. If I get the GL version it's using, it returns 4.1. If I try to time it with `glBeginQuery` and `glEndQuery` with `GL_TIME_ELAPSED`, it works fine. However, I would prefer to use `GL_TIMESTAMP` since I want the ability to nest these. Any thoughts why `GL_TIME_ELAPSED` would work but not `GL_TIMESTAMP`?

EDIT: For those with this question, I am using multiple frame buffering to get the results so CPU won't block, but even if I turn this off (i.e. CPU block till query result is ready), it returns 0.

EDIT2: Even if I do the synchronous version of glGet with `GL_TIMESTAMP`, that returns 0. I tried replacing `GL_TIMESTAMP` with `0x8E28` and still no luck...

Comment: Did you check for OpenGL errors?

Comment: I just tried getting `GL_TIMESTAMP` to work on my Mac (running 10.9.2, Haswell graphics). I couldn't get anything other than 0 either. I had never used it before, but I'm reasonably confident that I used it properly. Looks like it might be busted. No errors from `glGetError()`.

Comment: yea no glerrors. I guess MAC just didn't implement it... pretty sad why they would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is apparently cause OSX didn't implement GL_TIMESTAMP.